# Accidentally "marked for delete" files in Perforce. How can I reverse that?

Tags: perforce

Using **p4v** I've unintentionally "marked for delete" several files in my local repo. How can I unmark these items. These items may have new changes and I do not want to override them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In the pending changelist in the pv4 gui, you should see the files listed as marked for delete.

Select those files you do not want to delete, and **revert** them.

Comment: It worked! I was able to revert the files and that removed "mark for delete" flag. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just right click in perticular folder or files in P4V and click on Revert.
It solved my problem.